# "None of [Float64Index([56.0, ..\n dtype='float64', length=1057499)] are in the [columns]" Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nonetype

Please excuse any obvious mistakes as I am new to Pandas and coding in general.

I am filtering the original dataframe and creating a copy with chosen columns. This is how my data frame looks like:

(dataframe filter routine):

```
df_new=df.filter(['date','location','value','lat_final','lon_final'], axis=1)
df_new = df_new.set_index('date')
print (df_new.head())
```

The new dataframe:

```
    location  value lat_final lon_final
date                                                              
2015-06-30 09:40:00+05:30   XYZI   56.0   28.6508   77.3152
2015-06-30 11:00:00+05:30   MNOP   36.0   28.6683   77.1167
2015-06-30 17:10:00+05:30   QRST   71.0   28.6508   77.3152
2015-06-30 11:00:00+05:30   UVWX   98.0   28.6508   77.3152
2015-06-30 09:40:00+05:30   XXYZ   26.0   28.6683   77.1167
```

While trying to perform some operations on columns in this new dataframe, I am getting the none type error. These are the operations I am performing:

(This step goes fine)

```
f=df_new[df_new['value']>=0]
f.drop(f[f['value'] >1500].index, inplace = True)
f.drop(f[f['value'] <2].index, inplace = True)
```

(The error crops up here):

```
#Filteration steps:
#Step1: grouping into 12h or n hour intervals:
diurnal = f[f['value']].resample('12h')
```

Where am I going wrong?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This: `f[f['value']]` will give you an error. If you want to resample the `value` column, you should select it properly, and also tell `resample` how you want to aggregate the values (sum, mean?). Something like this:

```
f['value'].resample('12h').sum()
```